# Groovy Java 9 modules support

Tags: java, groovy, java-9, java-module, java-platform-module-system

I've spent some time to migrate my project written in Groovy to Java 10. Now it's possible to compile and run it. But still it doesn't use any benefits of Java 9 modularity.
Googling about Groovy and Java 9 modules gives almost nothing.

So is it possible to migrate Groovy project to use JDK 10 with Project Jigsaw modules?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Well, after a few days of experiments I come up with the answer - yes, it is possible to use Groovy with Project Jigsaw modules.
But it needs some additional effort.

Let's say we have following file structure:

```
├── build
├── jigsaw
│   └── module
│       └── test
│           └── Application.groovy
├── lib
│   └── groovy.all.jar
└── module-info.java
```

**module-info.java**

```
module main {
    requires groovy.all;
}
```

**Application.groovy**

```
package jigsaw.module.test

class Application {
    static void main(String[] args) {
        println "Hello module!"
    }
}
```

First of all we need to compile module-info.java file with javac instead of compiling all files using groovyc because groovy treats module file as closure.

Let's do it:

```
javac -d build --module-path lib/ module-info.java
```

**--module-path** will include our groovy.all.jar as automatic module with name derived from JAR-file name.

Next we need to compile Application.groovy

```
groovyc -d build jigsaw/module/test/Application.groovy
```

It goes smoothly.
After compilation we have **module-info.class** (aka module descriptor) and **Application.class**.

```
├── build
│   ├── jigsaw
│   │   └── module
│   │       └── test
│   │           └── Application.class
│   └── module-info.class
├── jigsaw
│   └── module
│       └── test
│           └── Application.groovy
├── lib
│   └── groovy.all.jar
└── module-info.java
```

Now let's try to run our compiled module.

```
java --module-path build:lib --module main/jigsaw.module.test.Application
```

And this is what we get

```
Error occurred during initialization of boot layer
java.lang.module.FindException: Unable to derive module descriptor for lib/groovy.all.jar
Caused by: java.lang.module.InvalidModuleDescriptorException: Provider class moduleName=groovy-all not in module
```

And what does it mean? I don't know. After a lot of googling I found [something similar](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/maven-users/201712.mbox/%3Cbb02abed-7249-7874-0039-612c273065ac@qos.ch%3E).

So we need to manually remove from JAR these files:

- /META-INF/services/org.codehaus.groovy.source.Extensions
- /META-INF/services/org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ExtensionModule

Finally our Java module is able to start

```
java --module-path build:lib --module main/jigsaw.module.test.Application
Hello module!
```

---

All manipulations were done using Oracle JDK 10 and Groovy 2.4.15.

Comment: Does this work if you need to say export a package from the module and said package only contains groovy source?

Comment: Realistically this solution's not useful.  Basic Groovy constructs don't work.  This change works fine from a regular (non-modularized) javac run.   #####
        println "Hello module!"
        println(["alpha", "beta"].size)
#####    
Hello module!
Exception... groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: size for class: java.lang.String     
#####  

Build procedure here works with Groovy 2.4.20 (latest of old 2.4 series) but not with 2.5.13 or 3.0.4 or 4.0.0-alpha-1 (after updating to use newer jar names, etc).

Comment: java command-line samples wouldn't need scrolling if you used short-variant switches -p and -m.